# Computer radiator air flow

Tags: cpu

I only have room in my case to have 1 fan attached to the radiator (not push pull). I have a cheap cooler-master fan blowing air through the radiator out the back of my case. I am a heavy gamer, so I was wondering how much airflow does the radiator actually need for my cpu liquid cooler?

Comment: cpu liquid coolers often come with their own cooling solution, so that radiator should be enough for CPU up to the TPD specified on the cooler. Now the big question is is the rest of the system (motherboards, expension cards etc etc) stays cold enough with only the single fan attached to your water cooler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tell is to test. Run some software that maxes out your CPU and at the same time run some software that measures your CPU temperature.